# On UNIX OS, for which of the following I/O devices the access is not via a special file of type "character I/O"?

Tags: kernel, usb, block-device, character-device

On UNIX OS, for which of the following I/O devices the access is not via a special file of type "character I/O"?

1. Mouse
2. Screen
3. Disk On Key (USB)
4. Printer
5. None of the above

This question is from a test on Operation System course.

I chose answer number 5 but my teacher says that the only correct answer is answer number 3. Is there a special case where answer number 3 on USB falls? I would be happy for an edge case so they can accept my appeal please and I will not fail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming "2. Screen" means a tty or tty-like device (like the console, a serial port, an xterm or other terminal emulator, etc), your teacher is correct.   The Mouse, Screen, and Printer are all character devices.   The USB drive is a block device.

Comment: see also [Device file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)

Comment: @cas I read answer 5 as being “None of the above [are *not* character devices]” (or rather, “None of the above [are accessed not through a character device]”).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a special case where USB mass storage devices *are* accessed using a character device: when they’re accessed using [the SCSI generic device](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scsi/scsi-generic.html). (That link goes to the Linux kernel’s documentation, but this isn’t Linux-specific.)

However that is unusual for USB devices, and you wouldn’t realistically use that to access the contents stored on the USB device. If you need a specific example, you can use [`sg_dd`](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg_dd.html) to access most USB mass storage devices without using the corresponding block device.